Выровнять один объект, относительно другого
Вопрос по софту Inkscape, создание и редактирование svg файлов
Допустим есть 2 круга, большой и маленький. Либо большой круг и текст.
Большой круг расположен не по центру холста.
Переношу маленький круг(объект либо текст) на большой.
Как мне его выровнять относительно большого круга, то есть относительно другого объекта. Расположить маленький круг по центру большого?
Второй вопрос, есть svg файл. В нем два объекта(patch). Я могу задать для каждого объекта свой цвет...
Могу объединить контуры в сумме, на выходе получу один patch.
Когда на выходе один(patch), в нем объединённые 2 объекта, допустим один по верх другого. Возможно ли задать если не в html, то в Inkscape. Задать для каждого свой цвет, при условии что холст будет прозрачным?
Возможно вырезать объект над одним, если не ошибаюсь это называется разность. То тот контур что был по верх, будет прозрачным, поскольку холст тоже прозрачный. Это не то будет...


Выделяешь оба объекта

Object -> Align and distribute

Relative to: Biggest object и две кнопки центрирования:




Good, как быть со вторым вопрос. Возможно ли делать так? На объекте необходимо написать текст, сделать его единым. Только для текста один цвет, для объекта другой, на прозрачном холсте.

@Dmitrii, разные вопросы надо задавать отдельно. К тому же, я нифига не понял.
